# How to indent when type } ) or ;

Tags: indentation

I found a way to auto indent when I type one of <kbd>}</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>)</kbd> using this code:

```
(setq mode-autoindent-list '(javascript-mode js-mode php-mode web-mode))
(defun mode-autoindent ()
  (when (and (member major-mode mode-autoindent-list) (looking-back "[});]"))
    (indent-for-tab-command)))

(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook 'mode-autoindent)
```

inspired by the code in this answer on stack overflow [Auto indent after inserting a semicolon or curly brace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648867/387194)

Is there a better way, maybe build in mode?

Comment: I'm not sure about what specifically happens in these modes, but you could try modifying the value of `electric-indent-chars` while these modes are active and `electric-indent-post-self-insert-function` should take care of it for you.

Comment: @wvxvw Forget about `electric-indent-mode`, that's exactly what I've needed.